# How to determine if a website is set up as a virtual directory or not?

Tags: asp-classic

I have this classic asp code:

```
'code start
https = lcase(request.ServerVariables("HTTPS")) 
if https <> "off" then prot = "https" else prot ="http"

'use the following for website (non-virtual)
TheURL1 = prot&"://"&Request.ServerVariables("SERVER_NAME")&"/"

'use the following for virtual directory website
TheURL2 = prot&"://"&Request.ServerVariables("SERVER_NAME")&"/Tawanda/NewTawanda/"
'code end
```

I am using it to determine the root URL (e.g. `http://myserver/`) but I notice that when the web site is configured as a virtual directory I have to use TheURL2 and TheURL1 if its not a virtual directory.

My question is how can I determine (in classic asp) whether the web site is configured as a virtual directory or not so that I can place this code in an `if... then...` statement?

Answer (score 0):

You can query the ServerVariables value of **APPL_MD_PATH**.

When you run your application not under a virtual directory (a regular web site), then the value should end with **ROOT**, if it doesn't, then you're in a virtual directory.

Try this:

```
' Check value of APPL_MD_PATH
If Request.ServerVariables("APPL_MD_PATH").EndsWith("/ROOT") Then
     'use the following for website (non-virtual)
     TheURL1 = prot&"://"&Request.ServerVariables("SERVER_NAME")&"/"
Else
     'use the following for virtual directory website
     TheURL2 = prot&"://"&Request.ServerVariables("SERVER_NAME")&"/Tawanda/NewTawanda/"
End If
'code end
```